# Partial Differential Operators on Vector Bundles

Tags: geometry, reference-request, differential-geometry, vector-bundles

can anyone suggest me a nice reference for partial differential operators on vector bundles? Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An excellent introduction to partial differential operators on vector bundles is chapters $10$ and $11$ of Nicolaescu's *Lectures on the Geometry of Manifolds*. The author has graciously put a full pdf version on his website which can be found [here](http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Lectures.pdf).